# Why grep shows me output that does not contain the search word?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, virtualbox, grep

I want to check if the sensu service is installed. I ran this command `service --status-all| grep sensu` and here is the output

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ service --status-all| grep sensu
 [ ? ]  apport
 [ ? ]  console-setup
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks
 [ ? ]  cryptdisks-early
 [ ? ]  dns-clean
 [ ? ]  irqbalance
 [ ? ]  killprocs
 [ ? ]  kmod
 [ ? ]  networking
 [ ? ]  ondemand
 [ ? ]  open-vm-tools
 [ ? ]  pppd-dns
 [ ? ]  rc.local
 [ ? ]  screen-cleanup
 [ ? ]  sendsigs
 [ ? ]  umountfs
 [ ? ]  umountnfs.sh
 [ ? ]  umountroot
 [ ? ]  virtualbox-guest-x11
```

I find it very strange that `grep` does not filter out all the above lines because none of them contain the search word 'sensu'

The question is: Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some services report their status to stderr:

```
$ service --status-all 2>&1 | wc -l
43
$ service --status-all 2>/dev/null | wc -l
28
$ service --status-all 2>&1 1>/dev/null | wc -l
15
```

28 to stdout, 15 to stderr. You are seeing the ones that report to stderr because the pipe only handles stdout. Do this instead:

```
service --status-all 2>&1| grep sensu
```